# How to get regression equation?

Tags: python, regression, linear-regression, linear-equation, pycaret

I am using PyCaret for comparison of regression models on my data.
After blending of the top 3 models, how can I get the final regression equation(model) of the blender?
Please help!!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: # Blending models
blender = blend_models(estimator_list = [tuned_linear_regression, tuned_support_vector, tuned_bayesian_ridge])

Answer (score 0):

lets say **lr** is the classifier and equation you want is ***mx+b***, you can get:

m=lr.Coef_

b=lr.Intercept_

Comment: this cannot work after blending of 3 models.